# Coveo Index Item Url Issue Using Sitecore 8.2 and Coveo 5.0

Tags: content-search, coveo

I am facing an issue with the Coveo index Item URL. After Coveo indexed on dev  environment, item URL formation is in a right format like `/en/za/news/news1` while on uat environment after Coveo indexed these URL is not forming in the right format, URL becomes `/en/sitecore/shell/za/news/news1`. Can you please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: are you using `Clickable URI` for the URL?

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat yes we are using Clickable URI, This issue comes after deployment, and it's coming randomly, some times come and some times not, I am not able to diagnose why this happened.

Comment: `Coveo.SearchProvider.Processors.ResolveItemSiteProcessor` processor in `coveoResolveItemSite` is responsible for resolving the `Clickable URI` and is usually set in Coveo.SearchProvider.config file. Can you make sure it is there in UAT, and also if `<serverUrl>` is set on DEV or not?